# Generate a list to feed of urls into web scraper

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops, web-scraping

I have been learning Python as a first language for a couple of months and am trying to build a web scraper which, rather than relying upon urls I give to it, crawls a website to get the urls for me.

I have identified which sections of the site contains the urls I need and know/think that I need 2 lists to do what I want.

The first, is a list of urls for cities, the second is a list of urls for units within those cites. It is the urls of the units I ultimately want to iterate over and scrape data from. So far I have the following code:

```
def get_cities():
    city_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('the_url')
    city_soup = BeautifulSoup(city_sauce, 'html.parser')
    the_city_links = []
    for city in city_soup.findAll('div', class_="city-location-menu"):
        for a in city.findAll('a', href=True, text=True):
                the_city_links.append('first_half_of_url' + a['href'])
    return the_city_links
```

When I print this out it shows all the urls I need, so I think I have successfully created a list of links here?

The second part as follows:

```
def get_units():
    for theLinks in get_cities():
        unit_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(theLinks)
        unit_soup = BeautifulSoup(unit_sauce, 'html.parser')
        the_unit_links = []
        for unit in unit_soup.findAll('div', class_="btn white-green icon-right-open-big"):
            for aa in unit.findAll('a', href=True, text=True):
                the_unit_links.append(aa)
        return the_unit_links
```

When printed this simply returns []. I am not sure where I am going wrong, any help would be appreciated!

Part 2 revised:

```
def get_units():
    for the_city_links in get_cities():
        unit_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_city_links)
        unit_soup = BeautifulSoup(unit_sauce, 'html.parser')
        the_unit_links = []
        for unit in unit_soup.findAll('div', class_="btn white-green icon-right-open-big"):
            for aa in unit.findAll('a', href=True, text=True):
                the_unit_links.append(aa)
        return the_unit_links
```

Comment: You need to provide which link are you trying to fetch?May be your missing to fetch something or may be you are fetching with wrong class.

Comment: I put the url in `city_sauce`, I was hoping that the `unit_sauce` would take each of these links, which are stored in a list, parse them in `unit_soup` and then go into each of the links and grab the hrefs at `'div', class_="btn white-green icon-right-open-big"` and then add them to  `the_unit_links` list, which would then be iterated over in my scraper. Any ideas? @PiyushS.Wanare I have slightly amended the second part, see revision.

Comment: It will better if you put data in one function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Crawls main site to get a list of city URLs
def getCityLinks():
    city_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('the_url')
    city_soup = BeautifulSoup(city_sauce, 'html.parser')
    the_city_links = []

    for city in city_soup.findAll('div', class_="city-location-menu"):
        for a in city.findAll('a', href=True, text=True):
            the_city_links.append('the_url' + a['href'])
    #print(the_city_links)
    return the_city_links

# Crawls each of the city web pages to get a list of unit URLs
def getUnitLinks():
    getCityLinks()
    for the_city_links in getCityLinks():
        unit_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_city_links)
        unit_soup = BeautifulSoup(unit_sauce, 'html.parser')
        the_unit_links = []
        for unit_href in unit_soup.findAll('a', class_="btn white-green icon-right-open-big", href=True):
            the_unit_links.append('the_url' + unit_href['href'])
        yield the_unit_links
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand how you are using this - your function will return after the first link in get_cities(), which may have no units? I think you need to set the_unit_links = [] at the start of the function, then move the return line of the function in by one indent - so it only returns once all links in get_cities have been scraped.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, unfortunately, that returned [] as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
def getLinks():
    city_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('the_url')
    city_soup = BeautifulSoup(city_sauce, 'html.parser')
    the_city_links = []

    for city in city_soup.findAll('div', class_="city-location-menu"):
            for a in city.findAll('a', href=True, text=True):
                    the_city_links.append('first_half_of_url' + a['href'])
        #return the_city_links

    # print the_city_links

    for the_city_links in the_city_links:
        unit_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_city_links)
        unit_soup = BeautifulSoup(unit_sauce, 'html.parser')
        the_unit_links = []
        for unit in unit_soup.findAll('div', class_="btn white-green icon-right-open-big"):
            for aa in unit.findAll('a', href=True, text=True):
                the_unit_links.append(aa)
        return the_unit_links
```

**Note:-** `Print the_city_links` and check are you getting expected output and then run another loop on that to fetch it's corresponding unit_links